# How to correctly use generics with protocols and different types?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have the script below written in Swift 5 and I am doing something wrong to configure the generics.

Basically it's a `Foo` protocol with a function with has an argument with a generic type and it's implemented in both `Fez` and `Foz`, where the type of the `bar` function is defined in the class definition. By using `associatedtype` is possible to fix this?

Any idea of what could be and how to solve it? Am I doing something wrong with the setup of generics? I need to support both `Int` and `String`.

```swift
protocol Foo {
  func bar<T>(zed: T)
}

class Fez: Foo {
  private var zed: Int = 0
  func bar<Int>(zed: Int) {
    self.zed = zed            //Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Swift.Int'
  }
}

class Foz: Foo {
  private var zed: String = ""
  func bar<String>(zed: String) {
    self.zed = zed            //Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Swift.String'
  }
}
```

Thank you very much.

**For the downvoter: I hope you have a nice day.**

Comment: @matt The first answer answers your question :)

Comment: Ok yes, but if that’s right, then you never needed to support String and Int; you support anything. That’s what I was asking you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic like this says that the caller can choose any type to pass to `bar`, and the implementation will handle it. You mean that the implementation gets to decide what type it can be passed, and that's an associatedtype as you suggest.

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Zed
    func bar(zed: Zed)
}

class Fez: Foo {
  private var zed: Int = 0
  func bar(zed: Int) {
    self.zed = zed
  }
}

class Foz: Foo {
  private var zed: String = ""
  func bar(zed: String) {
    self.zed = zed
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using `Foo.self` in some parts of my code and it's giving "Protocol 'Foo' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements". Do you know what I can do?

Comment: By simply doing ` let foo: Foo = Fez()` causes this warning. Sorry I am not good with generics in protocols.

Comment: As a rule, you don't want associatedtype. It's powerful and important. But if you're a beginner, then there are very few cases where they're the tool you want. Their most important use is adding additional methods to a type via extensions. So if you're trying to create things like `let foo: Foo`, then you're probably on the wrong path and need to think about what the *calling* code looks like. (If you had an arbitrary `Foo` type, what method could you call? You don't know the type of Zed, so you couldn't actually call `bar`.) So distill this to a more concrete problem and I'm sure we can help.